# Object pointers suddenly becoming undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, undefined

Is Javascript known to make object pointers undefined all of a sudden with no warning whatsoever?

I am passing three arrays of object pointers into a function and after a call to another function where one of them is provided as a parameter, another one of them becomes undefined after the call.

I have tried to pass that one into the other function as well and check at each step if anything happens to it, but nothing happens until control is returned from that function (with the returning of another array of object references having been built in that function).

I have also tried to clone it and and copying back from the clone after the call, still the result is undefined. Weirdest of all, I tried to build it again, inserting a call to the function where it is built after the call to the mentioned other function. Still the same.

The function where this happens is below. Note the identical alerts before and after the call to drawing. The first one works, the other not.

```
function play(skaters,nations,distances)
{
    var pairs = [];
    for(i=0;i<distances.length;i++)
    {
    alert(distances[i].value + ' ' + distances[i].unit + ':');
    pairs = drawing(skaters,i);
    try{
    alert(distances[i].value + ' ' + distances[i].unit + ':');
    } catch(err) {alert(err.message)}
    for(j=0;j<pairs.length;j++) 
    displayPair(pairs[j],distances[i],skaters,nations);
//  displayDistance(distances[i],skaters,nations);
    }
//  displayFinal(nations); 
}
```

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: yes, i think js doesn't like you. and without code, you're not gonna get much love here either

Comment: No, that's not normal behavior. You need to post an example of a code where it happens because the problem is most likely somewhere in your code or in a library you're using. (Make sure the example actually shows the behavior before posting it.)

Comment: *"Is Javascript known to make object pointers undefined all of a sudden with no warning whatsoever?"* Yes, the worlds most popular language is indeed designed to just throw out the value of some variables at random. And people say "there are no stupid questions"...

Comment: Well, posting this tiny bit of code here obviously isn't the right thing to do. Either Javascript is faulty or there is something basically faulty about my whole system. Since this is the first thing I'm trying to write in Javascript the probability weighs somewhat in favour of the latter. Still the building of my system went beautifully smoothly until I came to this point of totally mysterious behaviour, which so far has resisted every workaround that I've tried, so it has left me wondering.

Comment: Works as expected for me. http://jsfiddle.net/Ywsed/ Something in `drawing()` that edits the object?

Comment: I have checked. Nothing happens until control is returned from the function. But I'll go through my whole code to see if there's any incorrect declarations somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Neither `i` nor `j` is declared with the `var` keyword, meaning `i` and `j` become variables in the global scope rather than local variables (assuming you didn't declare them elsewhere and we're just not seeing it here, but that seems unlikely). If `drawing` modifies `i`, it could cause the problem you're seeing.

Without seeing the rest of your code (specifically the `drawing` function and anything it calls), it's impossible to say, but using the `var` keyword to declare variables would be a good start in the right direction.

Comment: Yes! That seemed to be the problem. I did remember to put in the declarations in the first few loops I programmed, but forgot it later, as they seemed to work anyway. Until that point.

I'm very fresh to Javascript as you may guess. Thanks for the help. Glad to be un-stuck and ready to proceed further.